# instead of click event function can you please change into mouse hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(window).ready(i), 
$(window).on("resize", i), 
$(".sidebartoggler").on("click", function() {
  $("body").hasClass("mini-sidebar") 
    ? ($("body").trigger("resize"), 
      $(".scroll-sidebar, .slimScrollDiv").css("overflow", "hidden").parent().css("overflow", "visible"), 
      $("body").removeClass("mini-sidebar"), 
      $(".navbar-brand span").show()) 
    : ($("body").trigger("resize"), 
      $(".scroll-sidebar, .slimScrollDiv").css("overflow-x",  "visible").parent().css("overflow", "visible"), 
      $("body").addClass("mini-sidebar"), 
      $(".navbar-brand span").hide())
})
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Does this code even work at all? You should really be using `;` to delimit the lines and not use a ternary for such a massive code block.

Comment: It is certainly a horrid abuse of a test+ternary and non-DRY

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? It is in any case easier to change

```js
function toggle() {
  const hasSideBar = $("body").hasClass("mini-sidebar");
  $("body").trigger("resize");
  $(".scroll-sidebar, .slimScrollDiv").css("overflow", hasSideBar?"hidden":"visible").parent().css("overflow", "visible");
  $("body").toggleClass("mini-sidebar",!hasSideBar);  // or just $("body").toggleClass("mini-sidebar");
  $(".navbar-brand span").toggle(hasSideBar);
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on("resize", toggle);
  $(".sidebartoggler").on("hover", toggle);
  toggle();
});
```